# Use wicked_pdf without asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, wicked-pdf

After the commit https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/pull/68/files in the gem `wicked_pdf` I'm not able anymore to work without asset pipeline.

Is there a way to make the railtie include the module WickedPdfHelper instead of WickedPdfHelper::Assets? (look in the commit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the non-asset helpers from that file into one of your application helper files.

This will monkeypatch the behavior of wicked_pdf_image_tag and the like.